# What was the Angelic Psalter that Our Lady told St. Dominic to preach?

Tags: prayer, virgin-mary, rosary

In St. Louis de Montfort's [The Secret of the Rosary](http://www.rosary-center.org/secret.htm) he quotes the Blessed Virgin Mary talking to St. Dominic:

> "I want you to know that, in this kind of warfare, the battering ram has always been the Angelic Psalter which is the foundation stone of the New Testament. Therefore if you want to reach these hardened souls and win them over to God, preach my Psalter."

At a recent [FNE](https://fneexplorers.com/) Timberwolf meeting my brother leader, Mang says that the Angelic Psalter is the Rosary prayed 150 times and the other leader Ricki Ticki says "Oh I thought that was the Psalms themselves".  The boys were a bit confused, but we muddled through without intense theological debate.

Now, (not to get all technical and worried about consistencies like I would over Star Wars) if she said that the battering ram has *always been* the Angelic Psalter, and the Angelic Psalter is the Rosary, then wouldn't the Rosary have had to have pre-existed St. Dominic.  But, if it is actually the book of Psalms that Our Lady was talking about, where did tell St. Dominic explicitly to pray the Rosary?

Answer (score 3):

The Angelic Psalter is the rosary.

See the "6<sup>th</sup> Rose" section of *[The Secret of the Rosary](https://isidore.co/calibre#book_id=6364&panel=book_details)*, where he contrasts "The Psalter of Jesus and Mary" / "Angelic Psalter" / "Our Lady's Psalter" (i.e., the rosary) with David's Psalter (the Psalms):

> Ever since Saint Dominic established the devotion to the Holy Rosary up until the time when Blessed Alan de la Roche re-established it in 1460 it has always been called the Psalter of Jesus and Mary. This is because it has the same number of Angelic Salutations as there are psalms in the Book of the Psalms of David. Since simple and uneducated people are not able to say the Psalms of David the Rosary is held to be just as fruitful for them as David’s Psalter is for others.
>
> But the Rosary can be considered to be even more valuable than the latter for three reasons:
>
> 1. Firstly, because the Angelic Psalter bears a nobler fruit, that of the Word Incarnate, whereas David’s Psalter only prophesies His coming;
> 2. Secondly, just as the real thing is more important than its prefiguration and as the body is more than its shadow, in the same way the Psalter of Our Lady is greater than David’s Psalter which did no more than prefigure it;
> 3. And thirdly, because Our Lady’s Psalter (or the Rosary made up of the Our Father and Hail Mary) is the direct work of the Most Blessed Trinity and was not made through a human instrument. …

Comment: "[If] the Angelic Psalter is the Rosary, then wouldn't the Rosary have had to have pre-existed St. Dominic?" Isn't the Angelic Psalter the first half of the Hail Mary? It is all from the Gospel of Luke and the prayer goes back to the very early Church.

Comment: @DarrellWright A [psalter](https://oed.com/view/Entry/153702) is a collection of psalms (songs); cf. "[Psalter of Mary](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=35891)."

Answer (score -2):

The rosary did predate Dominic by around 150 years. And, of course, Dominic himself never prayed the rosary. Nor is there any mention whatsoever of the rosary by his immediate contemporaries or close disciples.

Comment: True or false, you must be able to support your statements.